# Javascript how to push fetch data to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch, fetch-api

I'm just recapping some basic javascript any idea where i am going wrong?, i want to receive the response and place it into an array inside the function. The below is what i have tried.

```
  // simple api request
    
    function abs() {
    var a = []
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(res => {return res.json()})
    .then(data =>  a.push(data)) 
    
    console.log(a)

}


abs()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're getting tripped up by Promises!

Basically, you're calling `console.log(a)` *before* `a.push(data)` gets called because the `then` handlers get called *asynchronously*.

---

If you want to use the response from `fetch` in another function, there's multiple ways you can do it in Javascript. As @Matt linked in the comment, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) goes in great depth on how to do that.

The simplest way? Update your `abs` function to accept an argument `handler` and pass the data to the handler:

```
// handler is a function that accepts an array
function abs(handler) {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(res => {return res.json()})
    .then(data => {
        var a = [];
        a.push(data);
        handler(a);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks , yeah the console.log was for testing purposes i just want the array from the function to be returned with the data